# Open word via link online

Tags: cloud

Is there any way to open word file via link online? The word file is hosted in a server which is accessible via internet, but not sharepoint or onedrive.

I am hoping any way those word files can be viewed by the respective users without downloading directly in web only.

Microsoft O365 had a link, which used to support the functionality. Could not find any suitable thread regarding the problem.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I was looking for something like these. Found it.

- https://drive.google.com/viewer?url=
- https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).